# How to recursively process regular expressions in Cellfie? (For importing Excel to Owl)

Tags: regex, excel, owl, protege

I'm trying to import an Excel Spreadsheet into Owl, Protege 5.2.0. I already plugged in Cellfie, with which I can write rules in MappingMasterDSL to process Excel cells. I will walk you through what I'm trying to do using a simple example.

The sheet I work with looks like this:

[image]

And I have an original ontology that looks like this, where Color and Nutrition are properties describing fruits:

[image]

The effect I'd like to achieve after importing to Protege is the following, with descriptions of `Blueberry` and `Apple` on the right side.

[image]

The import rules I come up with so far is this:

```
Class: @A*
    EquivalentTo:(     
        ((@B1(ObjectProperty) some @B*([",([^,]+),"])) or     // Matching term in between two commas 
         (@B1(ObjectProperty) some @B*([",([^,]+)$"])) or     // Matching end of line
         (@B1(ObjectProperty) some @B*(["^([^,]+)],"])) or    // Matching beginning of line
         (@B1(ObjectProperty) some @B*(["([^,]+)"])))         // Matching single value (when there's no comma)
        and
        ((@C1(ObjectProperty) some @C*([",([^,]+),"])) and 
         (@C1(ObjectProperty) some @C*([",([^,]+)$"])) and
         (@C1(ObjectProperty) some @C*(["^([^,]+),"])) and
         (@C1(ObjectProperty) some @C*(["([^,]+)"])))
    )
```

The created axioms generated by the above code is a bit messy. The descriptions for `Blueberry` is:

[image]

Descriptions for `Apple` is:

[image]

So there are two problems:

1. You can see that there are some empty values after `some`. It's obviously from patterns that don't apply to that cell.
2. If there are many comma-separated terms in a cell, it will only find **one** term that matches a particular pattern.

So the questions are:

1. How to make patterns optional?
2. How to write recursive rules that capture **all** the terms separated by comma.

Many thanks for any help!

FYI, MappingMasterDSL for Cellfie: https://github.com/protegeproject/mapping-master/wiki/MappingMasterDSL

Regular Expression Patterns:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: `mm:capturing` can be used to do it for all capturing expressions in the regex. but I don't think it will work for class expressions that will the be the union of all captured elements. The example at least only shows that it works for simple facts, e.g. multiple firstnames, etc.

Comment: As for 1, possibly you could add `owl:Thing` or `owl:Nothing` in your Excel. E.g. `Blue, owl:Nothing, owl:Nothing`.